# How can I convert character to KeyEvent key code in kotlin/jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have an ascii character "o" coming from a serial port. I want to translate this into a KeyEvent, but I can't figure out how to get the correct KeyCode.

I can't do `char.code` because that gives me the ascii code. I need the `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_O`.